# Remove text between 2 characters but with conditions

Tags: php

I need to remove text in this string:

> bca.pzb. (4-86) 11,52 -eleven and fiftytwo-

I need to remove `-eleven and fiftytwo-` and leave `bca.pzb. (4-86) 11,52`

I tryied to study how to do that with `preg_match` and other methods but I don't know how to recognize the text that is between "-"..."-" and the "-" that is in "(4-86)".

How is possible to remove the text between "-" but ignoring the "-" in "(4-86)"?

Thanks to anyone for any hint.

EDIT:

Thank you for all the answers! As requested I report more data here. I have all rows of text formatted this way, they can change numbers and strings of course, but they all are like that:

```
54 pzt. 9,42 -nine and fortytwo-
66 pzt. 6,54 -six and fiftyfour-
23 pzt. 4,62 -four and sixtytwo -
dxd.pzt.(7-8) 15,17 -fifteen and seventeen-
dxd.pzt.(1-5) 5,84 -five and eightyfour-
dxd.pzt.(4-8) 29,92 -twentynine and ninetytwo-
dxd.pzt.(5-3) 4,61 -four and sixtyone-
dxd.pzt.(4-1) 4,42 -four and fourtytwo-
```

I have like 200 of these rows each time i load a certain web page.

I need to remove al the text in the second part, where the numbers are written as words, and leave al the first part.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Some extra info would be nice. E.g. does `-eleven and fiftytwo-` always match at the end of the string? Does it always have only non-digits while the other `-` is between digits? Every detail you provide helps building a sturdy regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've only provided one example, I can only guess at what you're trying to remove. However, you can try this, which removes the *rightmost* text surrounded by hyphens, and the single space before it:

```
$string = 'bca.pzb. (4-86) 11,52 -eleven and fiftytwo-';
$removed = preg_replace('/ -[^-]*-$/', '', $string);
```

Comment: there is only one space difference between our answers :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace("/-([^-]+)-$/", "", 'bca.pzb. (4-86) 11,52 -eleven and fiftytwo-');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like:

preg_match('/-(.*)-/s',$html,$content_arr);

results will be in $content_arr

Comment: this one may be too aggressive as .* matches anything, so bca.pzb. (4-86) 11,52 -eleven and fiftytwo- will become bca.pzb. (4

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to search for alpha numerical characters + spaces between dashes:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\-[\w\s]+\-/', '', $originalText);
```

It will work, but it removes all matches like -some text-, so you may be in trouble if there are lines formatted differently